# Get error: ImportError: cannot import name input_reader_pb2 when start tensorflow training in process C#

Tags: c#, python, tensorflow

Im trying to start a training process in c# using tensorflow lib on linux, the process will execute a python script "object_detection/legacy/train.py" in tensorflow source code folder.

My process setting:

```
var workingDir = "/models/research/object-detection";
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(workingDir);
var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "python",
                    Arguments = $@"legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir={trainDir} --pipeline_config_path={configPath}",
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true
                },
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };
```

I had set current working directory using Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(), but when I start process, always get error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name input_reader_pb2
```

I tried to run: `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`, it success with no error, but when start process still get `importError`.

But if I move to "/models/research/object-detection" and run command in terminal:

```
python legacy/train.py ...
```

It works.

This is my log:

```
[10/12/2018, 17:19:56]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[10/12/2018, 17:19:56]:   File "/notebooks/models/research/object_detection/legacy/train.py", line 49, in <module>
[10/12/2018, 17:19:56]:     from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
[10/12/2018, 17:19:56]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py2.7.egg/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py", line 27, in <module>
[10/12/2018, 17:19:56]:     from object_detection.data_decoders import tf_example_decoder
[10/12/2018, 17:19:56]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py2.7.egg/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py", line 27, in <module>
[10/12/2018, 17:19:56]:     from object_detection.protos import input_reader_pb2
[10/12/2018, 17:19:56]: ImportError: cannot import name input_reader_pb2
```